# FireBase - Observer Remove Child at specific path not getting called

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, removechild

I'm sure i'm missing something, yet not sure what. I understand that the concept of "Remove **Child"**, refer only to the child's beneath the parent. Yet, if i have this following structure :

```
Parent
      Users
           User1
                prop1
           User2
                prop 2
```

And i would like directly to delete User1(and observe it). So that's what i have tried :

1.First we add an observer

```
let futureRef = Firebase(url: "parent/Users/User1")
futureRef.observeEventType(.ChildRemoved, withBlock: {  ( snapshot) in
        self.gameOver.disableMatch()
                })
```

1. Than we delete

   ```
     let futureRef = Firebase(url: "parent/Users/User1")

           futureRef.removeValue()
   ```

**The observer doesn't get called,I know i can observe all of the "Users" category, and than check - but that's just wrong(think about 1000 users at the same brach, each deletion will get called **

**Any suggestion how do achieve specific location "Remove"?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should observe the parent node for changes in it's child nodes.

So if you observe:  /parent/users

any changes to any users (User1, User2) will trigger the event.

If you are observing /parent/users/user1 as in your example, any changes within that node, say a change to prop1, will trigger the event.

Comment: But as i referred above, if i have 10k rows at the same category, and each users observ each change. Seems like a bad idea?

Comment: That's actually how it's designed to work. When there is a change: add, edit or delete to a child of the parent node, only the node that's modified is sent to your app. So having a /users/ node with 10000 child users (user1, user2, user3, user10000) doesn't really have any bearing on adding, editing or deleting (performance-wise)

Comment: I been thinking on a work around, First change child of the child i want to delete, observe this change(childChanged), do what i need, and after that delete the whole child. Sounds good? ++ If it's designed this way - isn't it a lack of efficiency? 10K sounds legitimate amounts of sub-childs. I wouldn't wont it to try each change. Possibly could get to 10000^2 - 1 false calls?

Comment: You don't need a workaround; let Firebase do the heavy lifting for you. Observe the /users/ node and when you add, edit or delete a user, your app will be notified of that change and the node will be included in the snapshot. so you can process accordingly.

Comment: Hey Jay, Thank you for the fast responds. I understand exactly what u r saying, But i do care about user experience(too many requests, i know it's async task but still may take time to run on all records when app scales), and the extra thing is that my limit is pretty strik, I prefer not to kill my bandwidth for simple task(least what i thought). Is it actually the way you should do so?

Comment: You will not kill your bandwidth! If one user node is deleted, only that one user node is sent to your app. It's a tiny amount of data. Even if you bulk-delete 1000 nodes, it's a small amount of bandwidth. We've tested it extensively. You are not running anything on 'all records' only the ones that are added, edited or removed, one at a time.

Comment: Ohhh, I get it now, it will only get childRemoved, so even if there are 10k users online, only if all this 10k will delete their users together i'll get this amount of notification?

Comment: Correct. If there are 10k users online and all of them are observing the users node, and 1 user is deleted, all 10k users will be notified that 1 user was deleted. So the amount of data going to each app is tiny so there are no bandwidth implications. The sending of that data is handled by the Firebase server so you don't need to really worry about it.